# NodeJS spawn(child_process)

Tags: node.js

Как заспавнить фоновый процесс, и можно ли сделать так, чтобы потом можно было его выбрать и завершить?
заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл решение:

```
exec('start "уникальное название окна" путь к файлу')
```